# Connected Components with Periodic Boundary Conditions

Tags: c++, algorithm

Normally to find the connected components on a set of points, I build a graph from the points that are placed in 2 dimensional Euclidean space where the edges are determined with thresholding. Namely, if the distance between two points is closer than a predetermined cut-off radius, then I consider them as neighbors. Then I do a depth-first search on this graph to determine the connected components.

The problem with this approach is I have to use thresholding to build the graph in the first place. I am not a computer scientist, so I never took an algorithms class. I would like to know if there is an algorithm with which I can find nearest neighbors or connected components without building the edges with thresholding? The main issue that makes thresholding so preferable is the fact that this box is periodic. That's why googling alone didn't help me much.

My code for this look like this:

```
// +++++
// Graph
// +++++

// ( Note that edges are lines connecting nodes or vertices )

class Graph
{

public:
    Graph() {}
    ~Graph() {}
    void setNumNodes( int nds );
    int getNumNodes() { return numNodes; }
    void addEdge( int nd_idx, set<int> dest );
    map<int,set<int> > edges; // [node, destination]
    void setThreshold( double cutoff, double carpan );
    double getThreshold() { return threshold; }

private:
    int numNodes;
    double threshold;

};

void Graph::setNumNodes( int nds ){
    numNodes = nds;
}

void Graph::addEdge( int nd_idx, set<int> dest ){
    edges.insert( pair<int,set<int> >( nd_idx, dest ) );
}

void Graph::setThreshold( double cutoff, double carpan ){
    threshold = 2*R + carpan*cutoff;
}


// +++++

// Function for depth-first search from a starting node
int dfsFromNode( Graph& graph, int i, stack<int>& S, vector<bool>& visited ){

    int connected_comp = 0;

    // Add the node to the stack
    S.push( i );

    // While there are nodes that are not visited
    // (so as long as stack is not empty ..)
    while( !S.empty() ){

        // Remove the top of the stack (backtracking process)
        S.pop();
        if( !visited[i] ){
            visited[i] = true;
            connected_comp++;
            set<int> neighbors;
            neighbors = graph.edges[i];
            for( auto j: neighbors ){
                i = j;
                S.push( i );
            }
        } // if the node is visited before, get out

    } // while loop to check if the stack is empty or not

    return connected_comp;

}
```

edit:

To reiterate the question, how can I find the nearest neighbors or connected components without doing thresholding in periodic boundary settings?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Comment: With which of these algorithms, I can find nearest neighbors without thresholding in periodic boundary settings? That's what I want to know, if possible. As I mentioned, I didn't take an algorithms class before. So googling all these algorithms didn't get me far :). I just want to focus my attention in one of these, that works for my case.

Comment: @ozdm imho you should add your comment to the question to make it more clear. Actually in your question, you are not asking a question (there is a "?", but the sentence is not a question and its is hidden in text)

Comment: @tobi303 Sure that sounds like a good idea.

Comment: If not by a distance, how would you define the neighborhood of a point then? The periodicity isn't really a reason for or against the threshold. Do you really want to find connected components or maybe clusters? If it is the latter, take a look at mean shift clustering or any other clustering technique.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Distance is still the metric for neighborhood, I just don't want to use thresholding for building the graph.

Comment: Then maybe we have a different understanding of thresholding. I think of it as taking all edges that are shorter than the threshold t. What is the problem with that?

Comment: @NicoSchertler The problem is I have to make a choice on the value of the  threshold. Instead of doing this, I would like to be able to calculate, for example, nearest neighbor of a node, or the connected components from a node, without choosing a somewhat arbitrary threshold value.

Comment: You could calculate the threshold from the average point density. Or look into clustering. Mean shift clustering is a method that requires very few parameters.

Comment: @ozdm If you are looking for an algorithm with no parameters, good luck. All algorithms have assumptions and dimensions and they are captured in parameters. You could replace thresholding with another step (e.g. nearest-neighbor search) but those algorithms will come with there own parameters. Any data science algorithm that claims to not require parameters or user input is usually hiding them or making huge assumptions. I would suggest first understanding the dimensions of your problem based on data or subject matter expertise, then make reasonable estimates to design an algorithm.

Comment: @dpmcmlxxvi I am not looking for an algorithm without parameters. I am just looking for an algorithm that doesn't make use of thresholding when constructing neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding connected components, you can use kd-trees. A k-d tree, (abbrev. k-dimensional tree) is an algorithm in which you split your data points into two alternating between orthogonal directions in each degrees of freedom. I find the [following link](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cot5520fa09/CG_RangeKDtrees.pdf) quite useful for explanation.

Specifically, in the case of periodic boundary conditions, you can just ghost/image particles outside of the primary box and build the kd-tree including these particles.